# attach a folder of files into a jar

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-7

i am developing a swing application using netbeans 7.1.2 . In this, i am using some image files. The image directory is currently in the dist folder. I want to attach the files with the jar file so that i can carry it anywhere as a SINGLE (jar)file. can anyone please help me with a solution?

Comment: This was already asked. See the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096398/add-image-to-jar-java

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your project is Maven-based, I would place the images in the `src/main/resources` folder. Maven will automatically include the files in that folder into your JAR-file.

Otherwise, [this blogpost](http://capturevision.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/how-to-embed-resource-files-using-netbeans/) will help you out.

Comment: Am sorry, but wat do u mean by "Maven-based"? Also my src/main folder doesnt have any files other than the source code.(.java file). I copied the images folder in src/main folder. But then also NO change.

Comment: If you have a `pom.xml` file in the root folder of your project, it's probably Maven-based. If you have that, copy the images to `src/main/resources` (not `src/main`). Otherwise, follow the blogpost I linked earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Oi Mate

First Create a package(Say images) under Source Packages

copy all of your images to this package(when you create a package,a folder in the name of your package  will be created inside your project src folder, so copy images to it)

You can access your Images from your program as

```
        URL imageurl = getClass().getResource("/images/imagename");//assuming your package name is images 
        Image myPicture = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageurl);
        JLabel piclabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
        piclabel.setBounds(0,0,myPicture.getWidth(null),myPicture.getHeight(null));
```

Now use this JLabel piclabel

Answer (score -1):

Simple method : you can set your image folder to classpath and export jar file by eclipse.

Comment: Question is about Netbeans, so telling how to do this in Eclipse is far from useful; hence a downvote.

Comment: @mthmulders so Netbeans have not export jar function ?

Comment: @Jason That's not what he said. He said that the question is in the context of the Netbeans IDE. Providing a solution involving Eclipse IDE is therefore not helpful. Hence your -1 vote from mthmulders.