# Specifying images to my code (JAVA)

Tags: java, image, jar

I want to specify images of a deck of cards to my code (blackjack game).
Now if I want to show the image on screen I need to write the full path of the image from my computer, but if I create a JAR, it doesn't hold the images.
How can I make them be part of the program?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add images to your src folder - for example create package `com.stackoverflow.images` and store files into.
Remember about set your path correctly (for example `src/com/stackoverflow/images/yourImage.png`)

Comment: I tried to store them at the default package (because that's where my code is), but it didn't work... You think that I need to name my package?

Comment: genrally it's good idea to create package - try and we will see ;)

Comment: OK, I tried but it doesn't work :( I tried to put the image inside the package and again inside the src folder. Nothing worked...

Comment: Open your jar with winrar and tell what is inside

Comment: look inside jar - it might be that picture is there, but your paths aren't correct

Comment: I did not create a jar file just yet because I want to test that inside eclipse first. Do you need me to write the path?

Comment: playerPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("01.png")));

Comment: so the problem is that your program doesn't draw your picture?

Comment: when you store it in package, you can set path to (for example) `src/yourPackage/01.png`

Comment: Yeah!!!! It worked! The problem was that I didn't put src/ inside the path :)          Thank you!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Actually there is still a problem. It works fine on eclipse but when I create a JAR file and run it, I can't see the images. So I opened the JAR file and inside there are 3 folders, one named blackjack (I think it the package one - it contains the name of the classes + end of .class), the second is the folder of the cards (the images), and the third is a folder named META-INF and inside there is a file named MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: so maybe try to remove `src` from paths and create jar again?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do it, I can't delete that folder or to move the game+cards outside of that folder...

Comment: I mean to remove string `src` from path in java code ;)

Comment: OH! LOL! Yeah I tried it already before I comment :) It didn't work. also inside eclipse...

Comment: maybe this one will help :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153590/load-java-image-inside-package-from-a-class-in-a-different-package

Comment: There were several ideas, the ones I got is just putting the jar file with the cards folder in the same folder and it works. But I didn't understand the way to insert the images inside the resources of the project...