# JavaFX Application Thread - When using Gluon Ignite Dependency Injection

Tags: java, javafx, dependency-injection, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I'm using Gluon's Ignite dependency injection library and when I run this code I get this following error.

```
public void initialize() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(this.getClass().getResource("DL4JBeans.xml").getPath());
                dL4JData = context.getBean("dL4JData", DL4JData.class);
                dL4JGlobalConfig = context.getBean("dL4JGlobalConfig", DL4JGlobalConfig.class);
                dL4JLayers = context.getBean("dL4JDataLayers", DL4JLayers.class);
                dL4JModel = context.getBean("dL4JModel", DL4JModel.class);
                ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
            });
}
```

Error log:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at se.danielmartensson.views.NeuralNetworksPresenter.lambda$initialize$6(NeuralNetworksPresenter.java:140)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(GtkApplication.java:211)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:590)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.a(SourceFile:608)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:101)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.access$000(BooleanPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(BooleanPropertyBase.java:245)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:81)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer.show(SourceFile:285)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.showAndWait(SourceFile:559)
    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.e.c.b(SourceFile:77)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is line 140.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(this.getClass().getResource("DL4JBeans.xml").getPath());
```

It gives no File Not Found Exception, only Thread Application error.
Here is my gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.17'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'se.danielmartensson.Main'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version: '1.0.0-beta4'
    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native-platform', version: '1.0.0-beta4'
    compile group: 'org.datavec', name: 'datavec-api', version: '1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:ignite-spring:1.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.8'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'se.danielmartensson.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

One weird thing is that even if I got these errors, I still can use the methods inside the dependencies I just injected.

Here is an image of my folder structure:

[image]

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResource()` returns `null` if the resource is not found.
My bet is that it can't find DL4JBeans.xml.

DL4JBeans.xml should either be

- In the same folder as NeuralNetworksPresenter.java
- In a resources folder that is in your classpath and in the same package as NeuralNetworksPresenter (i.e. same folder structure)

Comment: Hi! JavaFX can find the DL4JBeans.xml. It don't give an "IOException File not found" exception.

Comment: getResource() doesn't throw IOExceptions as far as I can tell from the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: My DL4JBean.xml is inside the resource folder in package ""/se/danielmartensson/beans/DL4JBeans.xml"

Comment: Is NeuralNetworksPresenter in package se.danielmartensson.beans?

Comment: Nope. in se.danielmartensson.views

Comment: That's the problem. It needs to be in the same package in order to reference the xml file the way you are doing.

Comment: You could either use an absolute path in getResource, or use a class in the beans package instead of this.getClass

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153590/load-java-image-inside-package-from-a-class-in-a-different-package

Comment: Ahh! Now I understand why this. comes from.

Comment: Look at the update. I have placed a new picture. But now it gives File Not Found.

Comment: Different error: that's progress :P Does using FileSystemXmlApplicationContext instead of
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext work?

Comment: Yes! Now it's working! "FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/main/resources/se/danielmartensson/beans/FileBeans.xml");"