# Load image in jar, error in code

Tags: java

I want to reference an image in my project that I will package into a Jar file.

This code is not working:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Images/buttonBackgroundSelected.png");
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Take a look here [Add image to JAR Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096398/add-image-to-jar-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This constructor only works if the image is available in the file system outside the JAR file

```
new ImageIcon("Images/buttonBackgroundSelected.png");
```

You almost never want to do this. You *could* use:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = 
   new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/buttonBackgroundSelected.png"));
```

when the folder and image and the have been included in the JAR file.

However, loading images this way fails silently if any issues loading the image. Therefore use [ImageIO.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29) should be used:

```
Image image = 
   ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Images/buttonBackgroundSelected.png"));
```

The resultant image can be wrapped in an `ImageIcon` if required.

Comment: +1 You may also want to use the `ImageIO` API over `ImageIcon` as it will throw exceptions when it can't load the image for some reason ;)