# Where I keep my image files in java project to make .jar

Tags: java, image, jar, netbeans-7

I make a java project that show question and answers with clicking Question and Answer buttons using netbeans.I put those images in "src" folder.also those image put after encrypted.
After finished my project i made .jar file.when I run that .jar file it says 
"java.io.filenotfoundexception:"file_path"(the system can't find path specified)".
how can I solve this problome.
thank in advance.

```
  public static void main(String[]args){

      String imageName[] ={"A01","A02","A03","B01","B02","B03"};

      String imageNameEncrypy[] ={"A001","A002","A003","B001","B002","B003"};

      for(int i=0;i<imageName.length;i++){ 

      try{

        //FileInputStream file;

        FileInputStream  file = new FileInputStream("src/image2/"+imageName[i]+".jpg");

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("src/image2/"+imageNameEncrypy[i]+".jpg");

        byte j[]="NiTh5252".getBytes();

        SecretKeySpec kye = new SecretKeySpec(j,"DES");

        System.out.println(kye);

        Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

        enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,kye);

        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output, enc);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        int read;

        while((read=file.read(buf))!=-1){

            cos.write(buf,0,read);

        }

        file.close();

        output.flush();

        cos.close();

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Suscess");

    }catch(Exception e){

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

    }

      }

     }
```

decrypt code

```
    int k=i;

    String questionImage[]={"","B001","B002","B003"};

    String questionDecryptImageName=questionImage[k];

    String afterDrcryptName[]={"A.jpg","B.jpg","C.jpg","D.jpg"};

    try{

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("src/learning/dvd/Temp2/"+questionDecryptImageName+".jpg");

    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("src/learning/dvd/Temp2/"+afterDrcryptName[k]);

        byte j[]="NiTh5252".getBytes();

        SecretKeySpec kye = new SecretKeySpec(j,"DES");

        System.out.println(kye);

        Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

        enc.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,kye);

        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output, enc);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        int read;

        while((read=file.read(buf))!=-1){

            cos.write(buf,0,read);

        }

        file.close();

        cos.close();

        output.flush();  

    }catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Encrypted? What do mean you encrypted them? Also, please post the results of `jar tvvf <yourjarfile>.jar`.

Comment: i encrypted image file using java class.
also I wrote decrypt class to decrypt those image.
then I load those image to label.
@ElliottFrisch

Comment: How exactly have you encrypted them in java? Maybe post some code for us to look at

Comment: @csmckelvey
Is my method correct???

Comment: Please, format your code correctly

Comment: Is now OK???
I'm telling that there is no wrong in this coding.
I am facing problem in making .jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access files from "src/image2" because there is no folder in the jar.

Use `getClass().getResource()` like in the other question [Add image to JAR Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096398/add-image-to-jar-java?lq=1)