# Error while executing jar files

Tags: java, jar, cmd

Why do I get this error when I try to open a .JAR file from cmd?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sqlprojectgestor.Gestor.initComponents(Gestor.java:311)
    at sqlprojectgestor.Gestor.<init>(Gestor.java:28)
    at sqlprojectgestor.Gestor.lambda$main$0(Gestor.java:1017)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I try to run the .jar file with double click but it won't open...

Comment: It looks like an error is happening in your code. For us to debug it, we will need to see the code. Can you run the code from an IDE without issue?

Comment: I think the error is in your path for the image. Try using the relative paths.

Comment: If I run my program from netbeans there is no error when running it which is why I think it is so strange :/ @nhouser9

Comment: Does your code represent or use images in files?

Comment: Copy your `src` folder to the place where your `.jar` file is.

Comment: Yeah I'm using images for buttons @nhouser9

Comment: Tried that, but didnt work :( @chalithalawanga

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is caused by not including images in your JAR. Please see this question on how to do that: It may be that you don't include images as resources in your JAR. See this question: [Add image to JAR Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096398/add-image-to-jar-java)