# adding pictures to .JAR file

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, jtree

I tried to add 3 pictures to my program, but when i add pictures, created .jar file cannot start.

When I try clean and build without pictures the .jar file works well.

The pictures path: `D:\Desktop\Password\src\resources`

```
final public ImageIcon picture = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./resources/picture.png"));
final public ImageIcon picture1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./resources/picture1.jpg"));
final public ImageIcon picture2  = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./resources/picture2.jpg"));
```

From Netbeans the icons are visible, and a program works correctly.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add image to JAR Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096398/add-image-to-jar-java)

Comment: how did you created the jar file, if it is a maven generated artifact , you need to use the maven resource plugin properly because your resource path is not the maven default resource path.

Comment: Where are your pictured located in your JAR? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127/java-swing-displaying-images-from-within-a-jar

Comment: Probably a wrong resource path. If /resources is top-level in you jar, leave the "." and use getResource("/resources/picture_whatever")

Comment: My jar file stored:   D:\Desktop\Password\dist\Password.jar

Comment: I tried without "." When I clik jar file nothing happens. The program can not start.

Comment: @BirosAndrásDániel If you look inside your JAR file using something like winrar/7zip then you can check where the images are stored. Then you can adjust the resource strings to match this. --- Also, if you run the JAR file from the command line using `java -jar Password.jar` then you will see the errors.

Comment: I checked it with 7 zip. The program contains a resources folder with my images. But when i would like to open .jar file still nothing happens. I tried it also command line with no success.I generate .jar with netbeans clicked clean and build.

Comment: I found a solution. My picture extendsion was .JPG I changed it .jpg, and it works!