# How do I import a picture into my source package in my NetBeans 8.2?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-8

How can I import a background image from my file explorer into my source package in Netbeans 8.2, so that I can use it in a JFrame?

Comment: On Windows 10 with Netbeans 12 I simply drag it from a folder and drop it into one of my resource folders/packages under the projects view (Ctrl+1 to show the project view tab). I don't believe it has changed since version 8 so this should still work, although the project view may be a different keybind for the older version.

Comment: [Read this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42085817/4725875).